# cp not copying files?

Tags: cp

```
cp -v /var/www /var/www/dev
cp -vR /var/www/admin /var/www/dev
cp -vR /var/www/cron /var/www/dev
cp -vR /var/www/css /var/www/dev
cp -vR /var/www/files /var/www/dev
cp -vR /var/www/images /var/www/dev
cp -vR /var/www/js /var/www/dev
cp -vR /var/www/medlem /var/www/dev
cp -vR /var/www/snippets /var/www/dev
```

It is only the first one that doesn't copy the files. I know this is far from the best solution but yeah, it works kinda well a part from the first cp not copying. Every cp except the first one works. I want the first one to only copy files and not go into directories and copy. I just get the error

> cp: omitting directory '/var/www'

Answer (score 7):

By default, `cp` will not copy directories.  This protects you from accidentally copying too much.

```
$ cp -v /var/www /var/www/dev
cp: omitting directory `/var/www'
```

To override this default, supply the `-R` option:

```
$ cp -vR /var/www /var/www/dev
`/var/www' -> `/var/www/dev/www'
```

The reason that this was the only command that failed was that this was the only command that was missing `-R`.

Answer (score 0):

John1024's answer, does answer the question, however, I would argue that the reasoning is not wholly accurate. It is correct that, by default, the `cp` command will not copy directories, however the implication that this is primarily to protect the user from "copying too much" seems unlikely.

Ubuntu operates a Unix-style file system, which uses the concept of [`inodes`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) to describe a `filesystem` object, be it a file or a directory.

A directory is simply a list of names assigned to `inodes`. In that sense, the visual representation provided by the GUI is somewhat of an illusion, i.e. a directory is not actually a 'container' of other files, but rather a list of file names and `inode pointers`.

```
.....a directory entry contains only a name for the associated file and a pointer 
to the file itself. This pointer is an integer called the i-number (for index 
number) of the file. When the file is accessed, its i-number is used as an index 
into a system table (the i-list) stored in a known part of the device on which the 
directory resides. The entry found thereby (the file's i-node) contains the 
description of the file:...
   — The UNIX Time-Sharing System, The Bell System Technical Journal, 1978
```

From this perspective, we can see that copying a directory, would simply copy a list of names and associated `inodes`; this would be akin to creating a hard link to the directory. This is (probably) not the user's actual intention when copying a directory. In all likelihood, when copying a directory using the `cp` command, a user intends to make a physical copy of the actual data files within.

Therefore, I would argue that using the `-r` option when copying directories, makes the command explicit.